# how to update adb drivers for android phones?

Tags: adb

I am having difficulties in my android application because i want to run my project in my android device. I tried to install some drivers for my phone but still, it can't update the drivers and my phone is not recognized even in adb devices. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Run `android update adb`
- Run `adb kill-server`
- Run `adb start-server`
  At this point, calling adb devices started returning devices again.
  Now run or debug your project to test it on your device.
- If you use **Windows**

  If you don't have the android and adb set as windows environment variables, just go to
  `C:\Program Files\Android\sdk\platform-tools`
  (in explorer press Shift+RightClick in the white part and open command window) and use the following commands: `..\tools\android.bat update adb adb kill-server adb start-server`

Comment: android.bat does not exist.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 it is in C:\Program Files\Android\sdk\tools

Answer (score 1):

For android phones,
Turn on Developer mode on settings

For Oculus devices,

- Open Oculus App in your android/ios device
- Make sure the oculus device is connected via bluetooth
- Goto Settings, Click on oculus device name
- From Dropdown menu, click More Settings -> Developer Mode and turn it on

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find ADB required version 1.0.40 from [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AndroidSDK.PlatformTools.ADB/1.0.40) and it works like a charm:

D:\Setups\XXXXX\Lineage FP3\platform-tools_28.0.1(ADB_1.0.40)>adb devices
List of devices attached
A2XXXXXXXXX1    unauthorized